# Check links in markdown files on GitHub

Tags: github

I am looking for a program, browser extension or user script that can check all links present in markdown files in a given GitHub repository.

Any operating system, price, programming language or license is fine. I have a preference for Microsoft Windows and python if that's a possibility.

Comment: Are you talking about internal links or links to outside resources (http: etc.)? In the later case, have you looked at the possibilities of the w3d link checker (is working for html files, I don't know how it will go on markdown files, maybe you need a small script that filters the links from the markdown files and gives those to the checker. Checker is in perl though).

Comment: @albert Thanks, good to know, I am looking for both.